# Is there any way to change dialog cancel button in x++?

Tags: dialog, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-365

I am using  Dialog class to make my dialog. I added there custom lookup and field, but it looks like cancel button doesnt work as it supposed to work. I dont know a lot about Dialog class and how it works... Is there any suggestions how to change Cancel button to its normal function - cancel the dialog. Right now it throws info that is supposed to throw out on Process when u press Ok on Dialog.
My current code:

```
class copyline
    {
        public void clicked()
        {
            Counter                                 createdRecordCnt;
            Trans                                   trans;
            Table                                   table;
            MultiSelectionHelper                    helper = MultiSelectionHelper::construct();
            JournalId                               journalId;

            helper.parmDatasource(Trans_DS);

            MyClass MyClass= new MyClass();

            MyClass.dialog();
            trans = helper.getFirst();

            while(trans.RecId != 0)
            { 
                MyClass.parmJournalTrans(trans);
                MyClass.parmJournalId(JournalId);

                if (journalId)
                {
                    MyClass.parmJournalTrans(trans);
                    MyClass.parmJournalId(JournalId);
                    MyClass.run();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MyClass.prompt())
                    {
                        MyClass.run();

                        journalId = MyClass.parmJournalId();
                    }
                
                }

                createdRecordCnt++;
                trans = helper.getNext();

                
            }
            Info(strFmt("@LabelFile:Label", createdRecordCnt, MyClass.parmJournalId()));
        }

    }
```

I have class with Dialog object, validations, lookup etc.
Dialog on class:

```
public Object dialog()
    {
        Dialog                                      dialog = super();
        FormBuildStringControl                      control;

        dialog.caption("@LabelFile:Label");
        Journal = dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(MyEDT));

        control = Journal.control();
        control.registerOverrideMethod(methodstr(FormStringControl, lookUp), methodStr(MyClass, journalTypeLookup), this);

        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: Show us a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your dialog class (`MyClass` or `MyClasss`, there are 2 versions in your current sample, typo?). Why do you call `MyClasss.dialog()`, the dialog visualization is handled by `MyClass.prompt()`?

Comment: ups, that was a typo. Fixed already

Comment: I also added Dialog that is in class

Comment: In that Class i have code that inserts data to another table on run() method. Dialog is used to choose journal where u want to copy marked journal lines. With Ok button it works fine, but cancel button still shows that info, but doesnt insert anything.

Comment: `MyClass.dialog();` just shows/runs the dialog. This in contrast with `if (MyClass.prompt())` where you _validate the dialog outcome_ with an `if` statement _before_ running it with `MyClass.run()`. Do not call the `dialog()` method directly.

Comment: @Sander But is there a way to make system understand that im pressing cancel and it should print out anything? Right now  on cancel this info works aswell ```  Info(strFmt("@LabelFile:Label", createdRecordCnt, MyClass.parmJournalId())); ```

Comment: Move that `info(...)` inside the `if (MyClass.prompt()) {...}` block?

Comment: @Sander I tryed it aswell, but in that info() i got counter. It means, it will show 0 all the time... That info should be after while. Counter stands for record amount that is being copied to another journal. Its important to show on info that. Any solution for that? Problem is that - if i write info() after while , it will show same info for cancel button. I think while should be in another if  statement that checks if u press cancel or ok buttom... i just dont know how to do it. Never used Dialog class

Comment: I mean, i can just make boolean and set it true on that ``` if (MyClass.prompt()) {...} ``` And make another if statement after while loop, if boolean is true, throw that info. But i think its a bad practis for code. Isnt it? Trying to find better solution right now.

Comment: I just found another bug - If i select 4 records from table and press copy button, then opens that dialog and when i try to click cancel, it will close in only 4 clicks. It opens 4 dialogs. But if i press Ok no matter how many records i selected, it instantly closes dialog.

Comment: If a dialog is giving you too much trouble, then use a regular form with a [Dialog form pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/user-interface/dialog-form-pattern).

Comment: I've read your question twice but I don't understand that when you click on cancel button what will be happen?